# Jquery Autocomplete and UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

In a WebUserControl I have an input element and I want it to display a list of values using Jquery Autocomplete. It isn't working at all.

This is the script for populating the list:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Other one"
            ];
    $("#listaCecos").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

I stablished a breakpoint and found:

- When the .autocomplete line gets executed, `$("#listaCecos")` seems to be uninitiallized. In the console it shows the following: `[]`
- After the page has loaded completely, `$("#listaCecos")` shows the element correctly `[<input id=​"listaCecos" name=​"listaCecos">​]`
- Once the page has been loaded, I can execute the .automcomplete code (above code block) on the console and the input start to work OK.

So, I suppose it is not working because when .autocomplete script is executed, the input element hasn't been loaded properly (it is inside a webusrcontrol and it is invisible at the  moment of the initial page load).

Please help me to identify where and when should I put the autocomplete set up script so the input gets properly populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it. The input is inside an UpdatePanel and it replaces its contents so the autocomplete configuration is lost.

The solution was to re-configure the autocomplete feature on each end_Request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "ceshar"
            ];
        $(".listaCecos").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    } 
});
```